# Driver seat vs. Driver's seat

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a very important report and I am using the term 'driver seat' in it many times as a metaphor. For example, I say: 'A group of actors needs to take the driver seat'.

I just started googling the term "driver seat", apparently it should be 'driver's seat'. 
Now it is really hard for me to change this term, so I wonder how wrong is it! Should I go through all the trouble to change this?

Comment: It's not really "wrong" in real (spoken) language, because for many speakers the extra /s/ is either "underarticulated" or omitted completely. But most competent native *writers* would think your usage is pretty bad.

Comment: In my opinion, yes, you should fix it.

Comment: [This usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+driver+seat%2Cin+the+drivers+seat%2Cin+the+driver%27s+seat&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20driver%20seat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20drivers%20seat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20driver%20%27s%20seat%3B%2Cc0) may help you decide how far out on a limb you want to go.

Comment: Report is a formal document. So, you must choose the formal expression only.

Comment: Most, if not all, word processing programs have a Replace function, whereby you can enter "driver seat" and specify that "driver's seat" replace it in all instances.  That should be very easy to do, and you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking literally about a vehicle that requires a driver, the "driver seat" is a part of the vehicle for the driver to sit in, just as a "passenger seat" is a seat for passengers to sit in.

It could be said that until a driver is assigned to the vehicle, the driver seat doesn't belong to anyone. Once a driver receives their assignment and takes control of the vehicle, the seat belongs to that individual driver, so it can be spoken of as the "driver's seat".

In metaphor, a "driver seat" implies a position of control, where someone is responsible for navigation and the path forward. "Helm" is another word used for the same metaphor. It means the same thing to refer to it as the seat itself, or the seat that belongs to someone in that position. I think you may correctly say:

> A group of actors needs to take the driver seat.

You could also use the possessive form if you prefer:

> After agreeing to fund the the new production themselves, the actors were in the driver's seat.

Using the possessive may express your metaphor in a subtly stronger way, as it emphasizes ownership of the seat you're encouraging them to take.

You mentioned plans to use this term many times in your article. Note that it's possible to use the same metaphor too often. I would avoid using this one more than once, especially when in conjunction with the same circumstances and individuals.

Comment: It is clear from other people's answers that _driver's seat_ is an established phrase in English, and that _driver seat_, though it appears to be on the increase, is not yet an established phrase. Your personal ruminations on what _driver seat_ might happen to mean are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @ColinFine this whole post has been nothing but opinions.  I'd like to actually see a serious attempt at this question considering that the use of the apostrophe seems to ebb and flow with the tide of popular usage and opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Your report is a formal document. In formal English, it is "driver's seat", so you must not go with "driver seat".

Hope the thing is clear now.

Comment: According to Google Ngrams, the use of the apostropheless _drivers seat_ seems to be on the increase. There is a move towards dropping apostrophes in non-true-possessive usages (eg working mens clubs, travellers cheques).

Comment: Please justify your opinion.  I would like to know why it has to be "driver's."

Comment: I admit that apostrophe is losing the ground; but, it is yet to lose the fight.

Comment: The apostrophe is a red herring: if that were the issue, the argument would be about _driver's seat_ vs. _drivers seat_. The question is about a possessive construction vs. an attributive one.

Comment: @Colin It's not so clear cut. New 'words' have appeared, as in _working mens club_. When the apostrophe is dropped, as usage seems to license, who can tell whether the construction is attributive using a plural form or possessive omitting the traditional apostrophe?